# Are generics the answer to handling varying UI Elements concisely?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, devexpress

Working with Visual Basic (+ DevExpress, WPF) and I've got the fields changing colours based on some validation checks, but the code duplication is bothersome. I feel as though implementing generics is the answer but am struggling with implementation.

```
Private Sub txt_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles txtFileNo.LostFocus, txtDataLoc.LostFocus,
        txtCltName.LostFocus, dtCurYE.LostFocus, dtPrevYE.LostFocus, seMinThres.LostFocus, cboDivType.LostFocus, cboCltType.LostFocus
    Dim todim As String = sender.GetType.ToString

    Select Case True
        Case todim.EndsWith("TextBox")
            makeTB(sender)
        Case todim.EndsWith("DateEdit")
            makeDE(sender)
        Case todim.EndsWith("SpinEdit")
            makeSE(sender)
        Case todim.EndsWith("ComboBoxEdit")
            makeCB(sender)
    End Select
End Sub


Private Sub makeTB(sender As Object)
    Dim btn As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If commandFN.bValidNewClient(btn.Name) Then
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
    Else
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub makeDE(sender As Object)
    Dim btn As DateEdit = CType(sender, DateEdit)
    If commandFN.bValidNewClient(btn.Name) Then
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
    Else
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub makeSE(sender As Object)
    Dim btn As SpinEdit = CType(sender, SpinEdit)
    If commandFN.bValidNewClient(btn.Name) Then
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
    Else
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub makeCB(sender As Object)
    Dim btn As ComboBoxEdit = CType(sender, ComboBoxEdit)
    If commandFN.bValidNewClient(btn.Name) Then
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
    Else
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply cast the sender argument to `Control`?:

```
Private Sub txt_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles txtFileNo.LostFocus, txtDataLoc.LostFocus,
        txtCltName.LostFocus, dtCurYE.LostFocus, dtPrevYE.LostFocus, seMinThres.LostFocus, cboDivType.LostFocus, cboCltType.LostFocus

    Dim obj As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
    If obj IsNot Nothing Then
        make(obj)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub make(sender As Control)
    If commandFN.bValidNewClient(sender.Name) Then
        sender.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
    Else
        sender.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Because I'm an idiot!! (also didn't realize dev express items inherited from control)

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you can just use the base class, `Control`, rather than writing a method using generics:

```
Private Sub txt_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles txtFileNo.LostFocus, txtDataLoc.LostFocus,
    txtCltName.LostFocus, dtCurYE.LostFocus, dtPrevYE.LostFocus, seMinThres.LostFocus, cboDivType.LostFocus, cboCltType.LostFocus
    Dim todim As String = sender.GetType.ToString

    Dim btn As Control = CType(sender, Control) 'Cast to base class here
    If commandFN.bValidNewClient(btn.Name) Then
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
    Else
        btn.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    End If
End Sub
```